# Get request yields response with data in it, but when accessing .data specifically it yields undefined

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, axios

*Apologies if the terminology is not great, still new to fullstack.*

Hello! I am trying to get all the users in my DB. The `get()` response is `OK` as the client is receiving the response `(see image below)`

[image: Response is OK, data is undefined]

The problem is that when I try to fetch the `.data` I get `undefined`.

Here's my `Vue Component`

```
import UserService from '@/services/UsersService.js'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      users: null
    }
  },
  async mounted () {
    // GET request for all users.
    this.users = UserService.index().data
    console.log('The response is OK', await UserService.index())
    console.log('when trying to fetch the .data I am getting  ', await this.users)
  }
}
```

The index() function

```
import Api from '@/services/Api'

export default {
  index () {
    return Api().get('users')
  }
}
```

Everything works fine, except that I get `undefined` data...

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to fetch the data asynchronously?

```
  async mounted () {
    // GET request for all users.

-   this.users = UserService.index().data
+   const res = await UserService.index()
+   this.users = res.data

    console.log('The response is OK', await UserService.index())
    console.log('when trying to fetch the .data I am getting  ', await this.users)
}
```

You correctly use `await` syntax in the first `console.log`, which might explain why the data return correctly.